# Flask security issue with session and request repeater

Tags: python, security, session, flask

I'm using Flask builtin session mecanism.

Here is my understanding of session mecanism (with flask) :

- all session data are stored in a signed cookie (with app.secret_key)
- when a session data is modified, the cookie is changed
- session's data are protected against write client side (due to signature) but not against read

Imagine the following scenario :

- In my session I put a variable `try_number=3`
- Each time the user make an action, a decrease this number
- If this number is equal to 0, action is forbidden

The user connect to the application for the first time, the application send a `Set-Cookie: sesssion=Flask.sign("try_number=3")`, let's call this cookie `COOKIE_A`.

The user perform his first action, he send COOKIE_A, the application reply with `Set-Cookie: sesssion=Flask.sign("try_number=2")`, let's call this cookie `COOKIE_B`.

Now, if the user perform another action, but doesn't use `COOKIE_B` but  `COOKIE_A` again (using `curl` for exemple), the cookie is still signed, and will be handled by the server, with `try_number=3`.

Therefore, only using the `COOKIE_A` for all operation, he will be able to "spoof" session mecanism, and make unlimited action with the same session.

Is there any builtin mecanism to prevent this ?
(I'm not talking about snippet for using sqlite / redis, but builtin solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a failure of the security of Flask's cookies, it's a failure of your counter design.  There is no built in protection against [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

You can shorten the expiration time of the session cookie.  This doesn't really solve the problem, it just makes the window smaller.  It also makes the session inconvenient for regular use, which would annoy your normal users.

Ultimately, you'll have to store some information on the server and check against it.  You could send a nonce with every request and keep a store of which ones have been sent back, ignoring ones that have been seen before.  You could also just store all session information (except some identifying key) on the server side, so it can't be re-sent.